# Jni call in web application of tomcat at linux

Tags: java, c++, tomcat, java-native-interface

I created a web application having JNI calls to C libraries.
Used technologies:
 apache tomcat as server-7.0 
 jdk-7
 gcc version 4.8.4 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1).

I placed the *. so file in shared lib of tomcat and added a path catalina.sh, at the time of Jni call in application. It says the following error.

**Stack trace**

```
[jni.HelloJNI.sayHello()V] with root cause
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: sample.jni.HelloJNI.sayHello()V
at sample.jni.HelloJNI.sayHello(Native Method)
at sample.jni.HelloJNI.call(HelloJNI.java:22)
at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:86)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:439)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketWithOptionsProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2454)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: The error message tells you that your linking is unsatisfied. That is sayHello() can not be linked. So probably it is not in correct path.

Comment: Hi  deeiip, i have added those libraries in tomcat shared lib folder [ ie) $CATALINA_HOME/shared/lib]  and specified a property export JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=$CATALINA_HOME/shared/lib/"
 in catalina.sh path under bin folder

Comment: Please execute `ldd your_lib.so` to check the path of required library. You may need to set **LD_LIBRARY_PATH** before start Tomcat.

Comment: Thanks i placed libraries in lib64 folder in linux, it works fine for me.